# Uncaught (in promise) Error: The specified component controller could not be found

Tags: sapui5, upgrade

We have upgraded the sapui5 application from 1.44 to 1.56 version. My application was working properly in 1.44 version.

After upgrade it gives me below error.

"Uncaught (in promise) Error: The specified component controller 'com.test.ui.Component' could not be found!"

Note: Component.js is loaded successfully i.e no 404 error for Component.js

```
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
   src="../../../resources/sap-ui-core.js"
   data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m, sap.me"
   data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
   data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex"
   data-sap-ui-compatVersion="1.16"
   data-sap-ui-appCacheBuster="./"
   data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{"com.test.ui": "./"}'></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/style.css" />
     <script>
   sap.ui.getCore().attachInitEvent(function() {
   var oShell = new sap.m.Shell("idshell");
   var oComponentContainer = new sap.ui.core.ComponentContainer({
            height : "100%",
            name : "com.test.ui"
        });
        oShell.setApp(oComponentContainer);
        oShell.placeAt("content");
        });

</script>
```

Component.js

```
jQuery.sap.declare("com.test.ui.Component");
jQuery.sap.require("sap.m.routing.RouteMatchedHandler");

sap.ui.define(["sap/ui/core/UIComponent"],function(UIComponent){
    "use strict";
UIComponent.extend(
        "com.test.ui.Component", {
            metadata: {
                "name": "com.test.ui",
                "version": "1.0",
                "includes": ["css/style.css"],
                "dependencies": {
                    "libs": ["sap.m", "sap.ui.core", "sap.me",
                        "sap.ushell"
                    ],
                    "components": []
                },
                "config": {
                    "resourceBundle": "i18n/messageBundle.properties",
                    "titleResource": "title",
                    "serviceConfig": {
                              "url": "/sap/opu/odata/.."
                    }
                },
                "routing": {
                    "config": {
                        "viewType": "XML",
                        "viewPath": "com.test.ui.view",
                        "clearTarget": false
                    },
                    "routes": [{
                        name: "route1",
                        view: "Desktop",
                        pattern: ":all*:",
                        targetControl: "rootapp",
                        targetAggregation: "pages"
                    }]
                }
            },

            /**
             * First method of the component to be called. It initializes the odata and the i18n models, calls the super constructor
             * and initializes the router.
             * @memberOf com.test.ui.Component
             */

            init: function() {
                // Fetch the rootpath of the component
                var rootPath = jQuery.sap.getModulePath("com.test.ui");

                //Create the i18n model with the properties file and set for the component with the name 'i18n'
                var i18nModel = new sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel({
                    bundleUrl: rootPath + "/i18n/messageBundle.properties"
                });
                this.setModel(i18nModel, "i18n");

                //Fetch the odata service url and create an odata model and set it for the component with the name 'odata'
                var sServiceUrl = this.getMetadata().getConfig().serviceConfig.url;
                var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel(
                    sServiceUrl);
                this.setModel(oModel, "odata");

                var sServiceUrl1 = "/sap/opu/odata/...";
                var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel(
                    sServiceUrl1);
                this.setModel(oModel, "odata1");


                //call the super-constructor
                sap.ui.core.UIComponent.prototype.init.apply(this,
                    arguments);

                // Initialize route matched handler and router
                this.oRouteMatchedHandler = new sap.m.routing.RouteMatchedHandler(
                    this.getRouter());
                this.getRouter().initialize();
            },


            createContent: function() {
                return sap.ui.view({
                    viewName: "com.test.ui.view.View1",
                    type: "XML",
                    viewData: {
                        component: this
                    }
                });
            }
        });
});
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Project Structure

[image]

Comment: Try changing the resource root from `com.test.ui.Component` to `com.test.ui`

Comment: Hi TiiJ7, I have mistakely written wrong resource roorts path. now it is updated. sorry for that.

Comment: Is it now working? If not, maybe check this sample out: https://github.com/SAP/openui5-worklist-app/blob/61be382bed84b6a252a1a98d52d0e02103b734f0/webapp/index.html
There the Shell, ComponentContainer etc are properly declared as dependency.

Comment: I have added my Component.js code also,Please check .

Comment: It looks like you forgot to `return` the component you created (eg. `return UIComponent.extend(...)`)

Comment: @TiiJ7 , Thank you. yes u are correct . I overlooked it..